# How do I update a select option for more than one target?

Tags: jquery

I have several rows of data and I need to be able to target each row by the first `td` tag and then show the option that row has.

Can this be done with JQuery?

```
<table id="scontent">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="jqgrow ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
      <td>325</td>    <!--I need to target this first-->
      <td>JOHNSON</td>
      <td>
        <select id="activities">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
          <option value="1">Open</option>
          <option value="2">Closed</option>
          <option value="3">Available</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="jqgrow ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
      <td>321</td>    <!--I need to target this first-->
      <td>MILLER</td>
      <td>
        <select id="activities">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
          <option value="1">Open</option>
          <option value="2">Closed</option>
          <option value="3">Available</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the first `td`, to target the first `td`, `$('#scontent td:first-child')` will get you all the `td` elements which are the first child of its parent (`tr`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. I'm assuming that by target you want to attach an event handler and since you want to show "the option" that row has, I'm assuming the `<select>` element is hidden.

Every time you click on the first `<td>` of each `<tr>`, show the `<select>` element.

```
$('tr td:first-child').click(function(){
    $(this).find('select').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Josan. After all that, I needed `find`.

Comment: @NaN I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: I'm glad it was an easy fix!  :)